# How can I prevent from passing null of a different type to a function

Tags: kotlin

I was surprised that this code compiled in Kotlin.

```
fun foo(key: String, value: Int?) {
    if (value == null) {
        bar(value)
    }
}

fun bar(key: String?) {
}
```

As you can see `foo` passes `value` of type `Int?` to `bar` as `String?`. I guess this compiles because `value` must be `null` in this context, but apparently, `bar(value)` in `foo` was a typo of `bar(key)`.

Are there any compiler options to make this an error or a warning, or are there common practices to prevent this error? I'd also like to know in which use cases this behavior is useful.

I'm using `Kotlin version 1.3.50-release-112 (JRE 1.8.0_152-b16)`.

Note that this code doesn't compile (as I expected).

```
fun foo(key: String, value: Int?) {
    bar(value)
}

fun bar(key: String?) {
}
```

with this error.

```
k2.kt:2:9: error: type mismatch: inferred type is Int? but String? was expected
    bar(value)
```

Comment: Not having used Kotlin, I guess this compiles simply because `Int?` automatically calls its `toString()` when passed to `bar()`. If `Int?` is a number it will always be transformed to a string. Otherwise, if it is NULL it will also be passed to `bar()` just as NULL. Maybe my answer is stupidly obvious but I don't see why this piece of code should not compile, automatically casting parameters between compatible types seems logic to me.

Comment: OP is correct: the compiler is smart enough to know that `value` can only be null at the point it makes the call to `bar()`.  You can tell because IDEA highlights it as an automatic ‘smart cast’.  (Kotlin doesn't do automatic conversions, except for string concatenation and a few specific cases around numeric constants.)

Comment: You could make `bar()` only accept `String` instead of `String?`

Comment: I guess you might be able to use a `typealias` for the key type... but even if you can it's almost certainly overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> are there common practices to prevent this error?

Yes - avoid using `null` and/or accepting nullable parameters.

The method `fun bar(key: String?)` is actually two different functions - one with and one without input. The implementation could look like:

```
fun foo(key: String, value: Int?) {
    if (value == null) {
        barEmpty()
    } else {
        /*Something else*/
    }
}

fun bar(key: String) {}

fun barEmpty() {}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `bar` was in a library in my case and I wasn't able to split it into two functions, but thank you for your suggestion.